# Why is this probability being cubed ?

Tags: probability

If 3 ants are on three different vertices of a triangle. what is the probability they will collide and they can move along the sides of the triangle - so in this case each ant can move along 2 sides of the triangle. So why is the probability that they will move in a clockwise direction (1/2)^3 ?? and probability in the counter clockwise direction is (1/2)^3 again. I understand that probability of moving itself is (1/2) but why is it cubed ?

Comment: Because each ant moves independently with a probability $\frac{1}{2}$ to move anticlockwise or clockwise: $$\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{2}=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{3}$$

Comment: so what formula is this using to get this cubed result and why is it not addition of the probabilities ?

Comment: @Shaktal Sorry but, for independent events, P(A or B or C)=P(A)+P(B)+P(C) is as wrong as can be.

Comment: just imagine it as follows: there are 8 different ways the ants can move. 000,001,010,011,100,101,110,111 where 0 is anticlockwise and 1 clockwise. $2^3=8$

Answer (score 3):

Nobody knows what probability really is; but in the last 250 years we have learnt to talk about it coherently. When there are $3$ ants choosing one of two "equally likely" directions "independently" then there are $2^3=8$ possible cases, which for "reasons of symmetry" are equiprobable. Among these $8$ cases there are exactly $2$ where all three ants start to move in the same direction.

Answer (score 1):

For independent events,
$$
\Pr\left( \bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i \right) = \prod_{i = 1}^n \Pr\left( A_i \right).
$$
In words, "the probability of the product is equal to the product of the probabilities".

In your example, each ant has a $1/2$ chance to move either left or right. Presumably, these events are independent, as we are given no information about the ants communicating with each other. If we let $A_i$ be the event "ant $i$ goes right", then we get
$$
\Pr(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3) = \Pr(A_1) \cdot \Pr(A_2) \cdot \Pr(A_3) = (1/2)^3,
$$
which is the probability that all ants travel clockwise. A similar calculation gives $(1/2)^3$ as the probability that all ants travel counterclockwise.

To finish the problem, the probability that the ants *do* collide is equal to the probability that the do not all travel clockwise or all counterclockwise. This is given by
$$
1 - (1/2)^3 - (1/2)^3 = 3/4.
$$